# How to make the non-separable data to become separable?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, supervised-learning

Away from the common datasets of Iris or wine, let's say we have dataset of 3 classes and this data is non-separable. How by any way to increase its percentage of correct classification samples...for example from 50% to 80 or 90%?

Answer (score 2):

Your Question is way to vague.

If your data is non-separable, there is no way to separate them. Given the data, the classes are the same.

Maybe you are trying to separate them with linear model and they aren't **linear-separable**? So you need a non-linear classification like a SVM with non-linear kernel.